# How can I turn off ESLint rules so code compiles?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I am working on a project in VSCode, developing a React front-end application. Everything was working fine but I decided to clean up my code by using ESLint + Prettier + the AirBnb eslint guide.

I got this installed and of course, many issues came up. I started working through them, but these are causing the app to not compile. Ultimately, these are all code clean up issues, but now I can't get the app to run, and as i Make changes, I want to ensure I'm not breaking something else.

Does anyone know how to turn-off ESlinting in this situation so it will allow the app to turn?
Ultimately, it would be great if the issues appeared as simple "warnings" instead of "errors"...
I tried updating the .eslintrc.json file to change things to warn status, but it's not working.

There must be a simple way/toggle to enable/disable this checking? Or as I metioned, just have these appear as warnings for me to clean up?